# Obtaining Belgian pre-1796 information

Tags: research-methods, birth-records, belgium

Thanks to Napoleon, a lot of registration regarding births, baptisms, deaths, marriages, etc started to happen in Belgium from 1796 on. This helped me get to a point where I know all names (and often years of death) in my paternal lines up onto the father of my paternal (great-)*grandfather who died in 1740. Where can I go on from here though? I seem to have run into a brick wall because I am unable to find any earlier information.

Comment: I recommend taking it one step at a time.  If you **edit** your question to include the source(s) you have for Egidius Van Sever, it is possible that assistance to try and establish the identity of his father and generations beyond *may* be possible.  Removing brick walls is listed as on-topic in our [help/on-topic].

Comment: Alright, I am intending to make a separate post for that, however. I believe this question is best without the personal plug, as a general one.

Comment: This Meta question may be worth reviewing: http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1901/anonymous-questions-easier-to-answer-or-harder  My preferred way of working is to start with actual ancestors in order to develop more general answers but there are also people here who prefer to work the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the Belgian archives have a website, search.arch.be

You'll have to make a free account. When done and logged in, on the front page, you can choose between "state registers" (1796 - 1910), or the parrish registers (+- 16xx - 1796)

Then you'll have to pick a province, community,... and search for your ancester.

Comment: Well, I went there through the state registers to obtain all this information I have now :-) stuck from there on though. I also get the parrish registers information in the regular searches. I'm stuck here: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9460/finding-the-parents-of-guillielmus-and-egidius-van-sever?rq=1

Comment: The thing is, the "search for person" function contains errors now and then. You will always want to use that site to see an original document, or an original index.