# Finding the parents of Guillielmus and Egidius Van Sever?

Tags: 18th-century, marriage-records, 17th-century, belgium

So far I have found quite a bit of information on related family trees on myheritage.com (basically it got added automatically to my tree after filling in a couple) and on the following website: http://search.arch.be/

I got on my paternal tree up to:

Judocus Van Sever (1756 - 1830) x Barbara van Hemelrijk (1782 - 1843)

son of

Franciscus Josephus Van Sever (? - 1783) x Barbara Soetewey (? - 1760)

son of

Egidius Van Sever (? - 1744) x Gertrudis Van Baerode

son of

Guilielmus Van Sever x Catharina Verplast

I can't get any further than Guililmus though, and the only references I found to him personally was on the other people's family trees. I'd like to be able to expand on my paternal line, but totally ran into a brick wall.

Facts that probably matter is that Van Sever is sometimes misspelled as Van Cever (and Van Severen), and they've always lived in Wezembeek (which is Wezembeek-Oppem nowadays)

Evidence of all paternal relationships are found on the abovementioned website, which is basically a collection of different official registrations. By going to "persons" and looking up "Van Sever" as a name, all of this can be found.

The only thing that I  can not find evidence from is the last paternal link. I have seen Guilielmus' name appear as the godfather of one of the children of Egidius however, and since it's customary to make the grandfather godfather, that is a bit of supporting evidence. His actual fatherhood is based on secondary evidence from people's family trees on myheritage.com, however.

Comment: If you have located any original records to support the assertion that Guilielmus Van Sever and Catharina Verplast are the parents of Egidius then I think you should **edit** your question to include them.  If not, then I think you should say that in your question, and backtrack a generation to learn more about Egidius first.

Comment: That's the only thing I don't have official records of, only secondary evidence and light assumptions. I'll try to look further into Egidius first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this marriage index ([page 61,](http://search.arch.be/nl/zoeken-naar-archieven/zoekresultaat/inventaris/rabscan/eadid/BE-A0518_110429_109175_DUT/inventarisnr/I1104291091758545/level/file/scan-index/60/foto/518_0338_000_00006_000_0_0116) ) 
**Franciscus Van Sever** and **Barbara Soetewey** married at 27-01-1756, a number mentioned B338

There are no other Van Sever's mentioned in the index, also no "Van Cever"

I couldn't find the original, so the index is the only proof. For that you'll have to visit an archive in real life. Probably the Rijksarchief @ Leuven.

A "**Franciscus Josephus Van Ceven**" was born at 15-09-1718, according to the birth index ([page 34,](http://search.arch.be/nl/zoeken-naar-archieven/zoekresultaat/inventaris/rabscan/eadid/BE-A0518_110429_109175_DUT/inventarisnr/I1104291091758114/level/file/scan-index/20/foto/518_0338_000_00006_000_0_0038) )
He had 2 sisters, Elisabeth and Joanna, and a brother Jocabus Josephus.

And indeed, at page 51 of the birth index is the original inscription in the book, in latin and old signs
([Page 51 in the birth register](http://search.arch.be/nl/zoeken-naar-archieven/zoekresultaat/inventaris/rabscan/eadid/BE-A0518_110429_109175_DUT/inventarisnr/I1104291091752489/level/file/scans-inventarispagina/3/scan-index/41/foto/518_0338_000_00001_000_0_0091))

So, Egidius and Van Ba(e)srode Gertrudis had 4 children according to the birth index mentioned

But those were mentioned under "Van Cever". Under "Van Sever" there are another two, so 6 children in total

First was born in 1718, last in 1731. So I assume Egidius and Barbara are married before 15-09-1718.

On [this site](http://www.de-meiseniers.be/afstammelingen-Grimbergen.pdf) I found a "**Catharina Verplast**", born at 31 januari 1644. She is a daughter of **Roelant Verplast and Joanna De Clerck**. Roelant was a "meisenier", that's why the site mentions his family. They seem to be decendents from the lords of Grimbergen, families "Berthout" and 'van Bouchout'

And indeed, on the marriage index, I find a **Catharina Verplast** marrying "**Guilielmus Van Zever**" in Strombeek-Bever at 26 12 1665.
[This at page 61](http://search.arch.be/nl/zoeken-naar-archieven/zoekresultaat/inventaris/rabscan/eadid/BE-A0518_110429_109175_DUT/inventarisnr/I1104291091758466/level/file/scan-index/60/foto/518_0313_000_00004_000_0_0118)

The original inscription is found here at [page 56](http://search.arch.be/nl/zoeken-naar-archieven/zoekresultaat/inventaris/rabscan/eadid/BE-A0518_110429_109175_DUT/inventarisnr/I1104291091757792/level/file/scans-inventarispagina/3/scan-index/58/foto/518_0313_000_00001_000_0_0109)

You will want someone more experienced to look at that text, I don't know what the third line is about. Was mister Van Zever from "Holland"?

Catharina Verplast's original birth inscription is not online.

That should give you some working room. Try to find the documents connecting the generations.

Comment: Very exciting, thanks for this effort already!

Comment: Well, after that, I'm stuck online. You'll have to visit the archives for more research, although the organisation "Familiekunde Vlaanderen" might be helpfull. They have a FB page two.

Comment: It might be Gertrudis and Egidius were married in another place, or the online registers are lacking info.

Comment: I live in Leuven, so I definitely could go check out the Rijksarchief there. Wouldn't that stuff be digitalised in the online sources though?

Comment: Not everything is digitalised. They can help you out with advice and such. The facebook page of Familiekunde is also well-visited, and people there love to help out. I know also a guy in Leuven doing genealogic research, but he's running a bussiness, so that'll cost money if you want him to research. Probably he'll deliver high quality research with reporting and such.

Comment: I've added some more info. That's all I could find. Longer analysing and searching, eventually in offline archives will yield more. This answers your question?

Comment: Thanks a bunch for all the help! I'm wondering if I'm from Dutch descent now :-)

Comment: Well, a person that is more experienced in latin and decrypting the old way of writing will be able to translate the entire text. For me, it looks like "holland" is mentioned, but I might be wrong.

Comment: BelgianGuest can you maybe point me where on the full-written source the bit of text regarding Guilelmus is? I can't read any Latin at all, but at least knowing where on the page it is would help. Also, how big are the odds that the person accidentally wrote a Z instead of an S? :-)